# Connected components in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

Tags: general-topology

In the space $\mathbb R^{2}$ with the usual topology, I am asked about the connected components of the subset $A=[0,1] \times (\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in \mathbb{N}\}\cup\{0\})$.
I want to prove that $C((0,\frac{1}{n}))=[0,1]\times\{\frac{1}{n}\}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ using the definition: the connected component of $x$ is the biggest (in the sense of the inclusion) connected subset than contains $x$. (Here the letter C denotes the connected component of $x$).

Here is my attempt.  Since $(0,\frac{1}{n})\in [0,1]\times\{\frac{1}{n}\}$, and $[0,1]\times\{\frac{1}{n}\}$  is homeomorphic to $[0,1]$, which is connected, it is clear that $[0,1]\times\{\frac{1}{n}\}\subset C((0,\frac{1}{n}))$. Now suppose that there exists $(x,y)\in C((0,\frac{1}{n})) \ \backslash \ [0,1]\times\{\frac{1}{n}\}$. We define $U=[0,1]\times\{\frac{1}{n}\}$ and $V=A\backslash  U$. Both of them are open in the $A$ subspace toplogy (is that correct?).

Moreover, $C((0,\frac{1}{n}))\subset U\cup V, U\cap V \cap C((0,\frac{1}{n}))=\emptyset,$ and $U\cap C((0,\frac{1}{n})) \not =\emptyset \not = V\cap C((0,\frac{1}{n}))$ (in the last property I have used that there exists $(x,y)\in C((0,\frac{1}{n})) \ \backslash \ [0,1]\times\{\frac{1}{n}\}$, and therefore the intersection isn't the empty set). This is impossible because we have proved that $C((0,\frac{1}{n}))$ isn't connected in $A$, and therefore in $\mathbb R^{2}$. So we have $$C((0,\frac{1}{n}))=[0,1]\times\{\frac{1}{n}\}$$
Is the proof correct?

Comment: It might help to note that the space you are working with is a slight variant on what is sometimes called the "topologist's comb" or the "comb space" granted, usually this space also includes $\{0\}\times (0,1)$

Comment: The proof that $C((0,\frac{1}{n})) = [0,1] \times \frac{1}{n}$ looks fine, although it could use more detail in proving that $U,V$ are open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks legit. You can verify that $U=[0,1]\times\{ \frac{1}{n}\}$ is relatively open by considering the open subset of $\mathbb R^2$ that is $(-1,2)\times(\frac1n-\frac1{n^2+n+1},\frac1n+\frac1{n^2+n+1}).$ Do you need help with the component that contains the origin?

Comment: Since all the connected components must form a partition of $A$, can we conclude that $C((0,0))=[0,1]\times\{0\}$?

Comment: Well done. I would have taken the long road of supposing it contained a point outside that set.